# Singleton: is there a memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, singleton

This is a simple singleton:

```
class Singleton
{
    Singleton();
    virtual ~Singleton();

    Singleton * Singleton::getInstance() 
    {
        static Singleton * instance;

        if (!instance) {
            instance = new Singleton();
        };
        return instance;
    };
}
```

When main code calls `Singleton::getInstance()->someMethod()` for the first time, isn't the class instantiated twice? Will be there memory leak?

I am asking because *Visual Leak Detector* detects memory leak on the line with `new Singleton()`.

Comment: It's not quite a *leak*, since you never lose the reference to the memory. It's just not very tidy. To clean up, say `static std::unique_ptr<Singleton> instance;`.

Comment: you will need to provide a mechanism to destroy your singletons at shutdown - if you want to debug for memory leaks. otherwise let the OS clean up singleton instances that don't need to run shutdown-specific code (faster shutdown).

Comment: This isn't a Singleton. `getInstance()` is not a static member so you need at least one object of class Singleton to call `getInstance()`, after which you have *two* Singleton objects. I don't know where instance is declared but no one seems to `delete` it ever. So -- yes you have a memory leak.

Comment: Wow look at all these answers-in-comments. Sigh.

Comment: @KerrekSB I think it's a leak because the destructor might not be called.

Comment: You should return a reference here, `static Singleton&`, and declare `static Singleton instance;` No need for additional checks etc, and it's also thread safe since C++11.

Comment: @vsoftco: You have an extra `&`. But you make a very good point.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit just removed it :)

Comment: @vsoftco: Stole your idea for my answer

Comment: @KABoissonneault: It depends on how specific you get in your definition of "leak". A "definite leak" is one which is unfixable, like "new int;" whereas "int * p = new int;" is potentially fixable (by calling `delete`). Some call the latter "still reachable (but not freed)".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> When main code calls `Singleton::getInstance()->someMethod()` for the first time, isn't the class instantiated twice?

No. Calling a static member of `Singleton` does not instantiate `Singleton`, so the only instance of `Singleton` to exist here is the one you create with `new`. And you only create it once, because once `instance` points to it, you never call `new` again.

One problem you have here, however, is that you failed to make `getInstance` a static member function. I assume this is a typo/oversight since, otherwise, your program would not even compile. In fact, the declaration is ill-formed even as a non-static member. Furthermore, the constructor should be `private` to enforce the notion that only `getInstance` may instantiate the type.

> Will be there memory leak?

Yes, and this is what Leak Detector is reporting. However, it's minimal: the problem is that there is nothing to `delete` that singleton instance right before your program shuts down.

Frankly I wouldn't worry about it. This *may* be one of those rare times that a leak is acceptable, mostly because more than a "leak" it's just a one-time failure to de-allocate on process shutdown.

However, if you get rid of the pointer entirely then you can avoid both problems at the same time, since one of the last things your program does will be to destroy objects of static storage duration:

```
#include <iostream>

class Singleton
{
public:
    ~Singleton()  { std::cout << "destruction!\n"; }

    static Singleton& getInstance() 
    {
        static Singleton instance;
        return instance;
    }

    void foo() { std::cout << "foo!\n"; }

private:
    Singleton() { std::cout << "construction!\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    Singleton::getInstance().foo();
}

// Output:
//   construction!
//   foo!
//   destruction!
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c46486137edbd562))

No need even for a pointer!

This has the added benefit that the entire function becomes inherently thread-safe, at least as of C++11.

Comment: "Calling a static member..." - should `getInstance()` be static?

Comment: @Vladon ah yes it should. It seems that's the clear intent, though, despite the incorrect syntax.

Comment: Noting that in the case of Visual Studio, it's only thread-safe as of Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: @KABoissonneault: lolsrsly? Not that I'm surprised. Anyway I'll let the reader find out what parts of C++11 his implementation actually supports.

Comment: Another problem with the pointer version is that its destructor is never called which may or may not be an issue.

Comment: @Galik: Well, okay, I suppose I've used the term "de-allocate" a little too much here. I mean "destroy" in the broader sense, including invocation of destructors.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If I do this: `Singleton inst = Singleton::getInstance(); inst->foo();` - http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b15aa04bb2a1ec6 - How can destructor be called twice if constructor was called only once? Why there is no Seg Fault?

Comment: @vladon: The constructor was called once and then the copy constructor was called once. Two objects (one a temporary). http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e336e06b637aad82

Answer (score 2):

@LightnessRacesInOrbit answer is correct and to the point. Since your question is somehow dedicated to best practices when implementing a Singleton (which you should try to avoid btw), I'll give you my take on it. You can use something called the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to create a `Singleton` base class which takes as a template parameter the class you want to make a Singleton. Once you've done that correctly, creating Singletons is like a walk in the park. Just derive `Foo` from `Singleton<Foo>` and make `Foo::Foo()` and `Foo::~Foo()` private. Here is the code I use, with comments, <kbd>[live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/058088221f15646e)</kbd>:

```
// Singleton pattern via CRTP (curiously recurring template pattern)
// thread safe in C++11 and later

#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// generic Singleton via CRTP
template <typename T>
class Singleton
{
protected:
    Singleton(const Singleton&) = delete; // to prevent CASE 3
    Singleton& operator=(const Singleton&) = delete; // to prevent CASE 4
    Singleton() noexcept = default; // to allow creation of Singleton<Foo>
    // by the derived class Foo, since otherwise the (deleted)
    // copy constructor prevents the compiler from generating
    // a default constructor;
    // declared protected to prevent CASE 5
public:
    static T& get_instance()
    noexcept(std::is_nothrow_constructible<T>::value)
    {
        static T instance;
        return instance;
    }
    // thread local instance
    static thread_local T& get_thread_local_instance()
    noexcept(std::is_nothrow_constructible<T>::value)
    {
        static T instance;
        return instance;
    }
};

// specific Singleton instance
// use const if you want a const instance returned
// make the constructor and destructor private
class Foo: public Singleton</*const*/ Foo>
{
    // so Singleton<Foo> can access the constructor and destructor of Foo
    friend class Singleton<Foo>;
    Foo() // to prevent CASE 1
    {
        std::cout << "Foo::Foo() private constructor" << std::endl;
    }
    // OK to be private, since Singleton<Foo> is a friend and can invoke it
    ~Foo() // to prevent CASE 2
    {
        std::cout << "Foo::~Foo() private destructor" << std::endl;
    }
public:
    void say_hello()
    {
        std::cout << "\t Hello from Singleton" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo& sFoo = Foo::get_instance();
    sFoo.say_hello();

    Foo& sAnotherFoo = Foo::get_instance(); // OK, get the same instance
    sAnotherFoo.say_hello();

    Foo& sYetAnotherFoo = sFoo; // still OK, get the same instance
    sYetAnotherFoo.say_hello();

    thread_local Foo& stlFoo = Foo::get_thread_local_instance(); // thread local instance
    stlFoo.say_hello();

    // CASE 1: error: 'Foo::Foo()' is private
    // Foo foo;
    // Foo* psFoo = new Foo;

    // CASE 2: error: 'Foo::~Foo()' is private
    Foo* psFoo = &Foo::get_instance(); // can get pointer
    psFoo->say_hello();
    // delete psFoo; // cannot delete it

    // CASE 3: error: use of deleted function 'Foo::Foo(const Foo&)'
    // Foo foo(sFoo);

    // CASE 4: error: use of deleted function 'Foo& Foo::operator=(const Foo&)'
    // sFoo = sAnotherFoo;

    // CASE 5: error: 'Singleton<T>::Singleton() [with T = Foo]' is protected
    // Singleton<Foo> direct_sFoo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`new Singleton()` does not have a matching `delete`, so yea, you are leaking a resource.

You'll get memory back when the program closes, but not all resources are returned when the program ends.

You can fix it by making instance a `std::auto_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`.  Or just don't use a pointer.

Comment: Please do not recommend using deprecated objects.

Comment: Which resources won't be returned when the program ends? And on which system?

Comment: @KABoissonneault It's not a C++11 question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I dunno, maybe it's a network connection with hello/goodbye handshaking?

Comment: @QuestionC: We're in 2015 now, so it's a C++11/C++14 question by default. If only C++03 may be used, that needs to be stated. That technology is twelve years (_seventeen_ by some definitions) old! Regardless, `std::auto_ptr` was deprecated for a very good reason, so recommending its use to language newcomers is irresponsible.

Comment: @QuestionC: Why on earth would you implement that with a singleton?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It could be a singleton "Logger" class that sends its content to a remote server when the program stops executing. You never know.

Comment: @KABoissonneault: You wouldn't do that in the destructor of an object with static storage duration (or, frankly, in any destructor). You'd plug it into your event/message dispatcher and have it take over during a shutdown phase.