# Singleton: how can destructor be called twice?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton, destructor

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30602861/560648) about singleton implementation a few minutes ago, I've got very good answer from @LightnessRacesinOrbit.

But I cannot understand why in the next example if I instantiate `Singleton` in variable `inst` its destructor called twice?

```
#include <iostream>

class Singleton
{
public:
    ~Singleton()  { std::cout << "destruction!\n"; }

    static Singleton& getInstance() 
    {
        static Singleton instance;
        return instance;
    }

    void foo() { std::cout << "foo!\n"; }

private:
    Singleton() { std::cout << "construction!\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    Singleton inst = Singleton::getInstance();
    inst.foo();
}
```

Output:

```
construction!
foo!
destruction!
destruction!
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b15aa04bb2a1ec6)

To be more correct, I understand **why** it is called twice. But I cannot understand **how** it can be called twice if after first destructor the instance of the class was destroyed? Why there is no exception?

Or it *was not* destroyed? Why?

Comment: Add `Singleton(Singleton const&) { std::cout << "copy construction!\n"; }` to your example and all will be revealed.

Comment: You should make the class non-copiable and non-movable: `Singleton(Singleton const&) = delete; Singleton(Singleton &&) = delete; Singleton &operator=(Singleton const&) = delete;Singleton operator=(Singleton &&) = delete;`

Comment: You have **two** instances of `Singleton` type in your program. One is `static` inside `getInstance`. Another is local inside `main`. Each object gets destroyed eventually. Hence two destructor calls. Why does it surprise you that the destructor is called twice?

Comment: @AnT because I am newbie. Thank you all. Now I understand.

Comment: I recommend reading this: http://jalf.dk/blog/2010/03/singletons-solving-problems-you-didnt-know-you-never-had-since-1995/

Comment: Sorry, I should have deleted the copy constructor and assignment operator. Although in a sense I'm glad I didn't because then you got to ask this :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit And after getting comfortable writing and using Singleton's, they can proceed to [learning to avoid using them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons) :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This line

```
Singleton inst = Singleton::getInstance();
```

Should be

```
Singleton& inst = Singleton::getInstance();
```

Then you would only see one destructor call.

The way it is written, `Singleton::getInstance()` returns a reference, but then **copies** it to `inst`. So both the `Singleton` returned from your function **and** the copy are destroyed. You never saw the copy get constructed because the default constructor was not used, the copy constructor was.

In the second method, the reference is returned, then you just have `inst` be a reference to that `Singleton` instead of making a copy.

As other's have mentioned, you can make the class non-copyable and non-movable to prevent this

```
Singleton(Singleton const&) = delete;             // Copy construct
Singleton(Singleton&&) = delete;                  // Move construct
Singleton& operator=(Singleton const&) = delete;  // Copy assign
Singleton& operator=(Singleton &&) = delete;      // Move assign
```

Comment: Yup. If you really want a singleton to be a singleton, you'll need to delete its copy constructor or make it private.

Comment: There is no need to explicitly delete the rvalue-reference-versions as the compiler will not auto-generate them.

Comment: There's no _need_ for a lot of things

Answer (score 8):

The line

```
Singleton inst = Singleton::getInstance();
```

copies your instance with the auto-generated copy-constructor. To prevent this from happening, add

```
Singleton( const Singleton& ) = delete;
```

to your class to prevent those accidential copies. To make sure that even more obscure mistakes are caught, also add

```
void operator=( const Singleton& ) = delete;
```

as well. You don't have to explicitly delete move construction or assignment as the compiler will not generate them with the other (deleted) members declared.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ In theory you are right, but for a singleton, there shouldn't exist a second instance to assign to begin with ;) But yes, it is possible to end up with stupid code that accidentally triggers assignment, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @DanielFrey I guess one can do `Singleton::getInstance() = Singleton::getInstance();`, which is really out of bounds, but still doable ;)

Comment: @vsoftco Yes, but that is not an accident anymore, it's asking for trouble. :-D

Comment: If it can be done, eventually some one will do it :D But I totally agree, it is asking for trouble.

Comment: @vsoftco That's why I consider being slightly paranoid to be an asset for a software developer :-P

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a public copy-constructor:

```
Singleton(const Singleton&) { std::cout << "copy construction!\n"; }
```

Your output will become:

```
construction!
copy construction!
foo!
destruction!
destruction!
```

There are two "singletons" alive because the one from `getInstance()` got copied. To avoid inadvertently copying singletons, you should delete the copy constructor and assignment operators:

```
Singleton(const Singleton&) = delete;
Singleton& operator=(const Singleton&) = delete;
```

Comment: There's something satisfying about seeing debug output I chose arbitrarily make its way through two people to another post :)

Comment: It sounds so happy too!

Answer (score 2):

You may hide the singleton in a regular class not exhibiting its static nature:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Singleton // A bad name for a specific class, you should not generalize
{
    private:
    struct Context {
        std::string name;
        Context()
        :   name("Hello")
        {}
    };

    private:
    static Context& context() { static Context result; return result; }

    public:
    const std::string& name() const { return context().name; }
};

int main()
{
    Singleton a;
    std::cout << a.name() << '\n';
}
```